Организация проекта с несколькими модулями в GO
Использую workspace для многомодульного проекта go, в котором есть 2 микросервиса, но 2 модуль использует некоторые пакеты из 1, чтобы не переписывать одни и теже функции. Возникают проблемы при написании dockerfile, т.к. 2 сервису помимо библиотек нужны пакеты из того самого сервиса, которые не копируются в контейнер. В корне проекта делать dockerfile не вариант, т.к. их несколько надо.
